# Auth token gets invalidates for unknown reason

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api/angular app, which uses bearer tokens for authentication.

The token just stops working after some time, and server starts to throw 401/unauthorized response.
Since it all happens automatically, I'm not sure how to debug this.

The token is being sent in headers, and works for first few requests.

Any ideas on  how to debug it or what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with a hosting.

I did not have this problem on my local machine, I moved the app to a different hosting provider and the issue just went away.

Answer (score 1):

The web-api uses `AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan` to specify the time before tokens expire and the default is 20 mins.

You can set this within your configuration setup i.e.

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(999999)
            };
```

[**OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserveroptions.accesstokenexpiretimespan(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: I'll check, but it doesn't even get to 20 minutes, it can stop working in well under 5 minutes.

Comment: @Eugene Are you passing it across each time in the AuthHeader? It could be getting corrupt or being dropped.

Comment: Yeah, its in a header with every request. Its definitely passed, and not even sure how it can get corrupt?

Comment: Is the Auth server (the one which generates token) is same as the one which uses it? IF not do they have same machine key?